# I would like to use Google script to send an email (from a form) to include an accept/reject button

Tags: javascript, forms, email, html-email

I would like to use Google script to send an email (from a form) to include an **accept/reject**  button.
I currently know how to send an email automatically from an updated form. However, I wish the email to have two buttons which either accept or reject the new form (it's a form for requesting annual company leave).
I can get the email to mention start and end dates, etc., but I don't know how to include buttons.

Thanks in advance.

Gavin.